# FileUriExposedException when create separate folder for captured images

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to store camera captured images at separate folder using below code but when i execute this code i am getting exception and i tried lot for getting solution but no use can some one help me please

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyRamImages/FILENAME.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

### code:-

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "FILENAME-"+ n +".jpg";
File image = new File(imagesFolder, fname);
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Comment: You should use a FileProvider which you would have known already if you once had googled for this exception. So @Sandeep Kumar gave the right answer. I wonder why you went with that other answer that only gives you a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just capture the image then in onActivityResult get the image as bitmap then save that to the path you want to save.

```
private void openCamera()
{
        // Start the camera and take the image
        // handle the storage part in on activity result
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And inside on activity result method write the following code.

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
{
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {
         Bitmap imgBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         File imageFolder = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        "FolderName" + File.separator + "InsideFolderName");

         if (!imageFolder.isDirectory())
         {
              imageFolder.mkdirs();
         }

         File mediaFile = new File(imageFolder + File.separator + "img_" +
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

         FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
         imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
         fileOutputStream.close();
     }
}
```

This works for me in 7.1.1 and lower versions as well.

Comment: you know how to add geotag for capture images?

Comment: `This works for me in 7.1.1 and lower versions as well.` ?? One time maybe. But the second time -if the directory already exists- it does nothing.

Comment: `in onActivityResult get the image as bitmap then save that `. That is not the image. That is only a thumnail of the image.

Comment: @greenapps -- it's just a brackets mismatch. Edited the code.

Comment: Further you should check the return value of mkdirs() as it might fail to create a directory. In that case you should display a toast and return. Now you blindly continue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return `Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);` do

```
return FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                  mediaFile);
```

That would require you to add a provider to the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
  <application
  ...
  <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
  </provider>
 </application>
```

And then create a provider_paths.xml file in xml folder under res folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Once refer this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Comment: what is this provider_paths?