# Camera Intent, FileUriExposedException, saving image in storage and retrieving the image bitmap and file path

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-7.0-nougat

On android devices below Nougat I have no problem saving images in the device's external storage and then storing the file path and displaying the image with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

However when tested on a Nougat device, I started getting FileUriExposedException whenever I start the camera intent.

I added fileprovider in manifest and also added a filepaths.xml

Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />

    </provider>
```

filepaths.xml:

```
<paths>
<external-path name="mediaimages" path="." />
</paths>
```

Here's my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
 Intent takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            String authorities = getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";

                            File image = getTempFile(AddListingPage2Activity.this);
                            try {
                                image.createNewFile(); //Getting ignore warning
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddListingPage2Activity.this, authorities, image);
                            mImageFileUri = imageUri;

                            takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                            startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQ);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
           case CAMERA_REQ:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              //How to get bitmap and create file to store in storage
                 Bitmap bitmap = null;
                 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileUri.getPath()); //returns null

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageFileUri); //returns null as well
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

}

private File getTempFile(Context context) {
        final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName());
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir(); //Getting ignored warning
        }
        return new File(path, "myImage.jpg");
    }
```

How do I save the image file and retrieve the file path in *OnActivityResult*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771172/fileuriexposedexception-when-create-separate-folder-for-captured-images

Comment: `How do I save the image file` ??? The camera app will save the image to file. Thats why you used EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: And further you know already the file path as you determined it.

Comment: `path.mkdir(); //Getting ignored warning` Do not ignore return values. But handle accordingly.

Comment: But when i run this

`bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageFileUri);`

It returns null

Comment: Yes. Why didnt you tell before? But your should not ignore return values to begin with. Handle them first. Adapt your code.

Comment: And check if the camera app created the jpg file first. It should be on your device. Tell us if it is there!

Comment: I checked my SD card and looked into the file and apparently a directory myImage.jpg was created, not a file. Oh I've also added `bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageFileUri);` to the question.

Comment: @greenapps In my file explorer, I deleted the myImage.jpg, I believe it was created when I was doing a bunch of coding and testing. So after removing the myImage.jpg directory, now I was finally able to save the images. Now I'm not sure if this is the main cause of the problem so I will continue to do more testing but it's a step in the right direction. I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why the camera app was unable to save the image. The app was supposed to save an image in **./packagename/myImage.jpg** but myImage.jpg was created as a directory. After I deleted the folder and tried running the app, I was finally able to save the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should be update filepaths.xml

```
   <paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

and Mainifest.xml file

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```