# Trying to access camera on Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

So I have been working on Android studio for the first time and I have a very important project. I am trying to make a screen which shows a camera (like snapchat ui) with some buttons on top, like this:

[image]

Now I am writing the following code:

```
package com.none.www.aarogya;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10;
    private ImageView imgDumpCam;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        imgDumpCam = findViewById(R.id.imgDumpCam);


        btnTake = h(View v); {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //If user choose okay than following code will work
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                //we are hearing back from camera
            Bitmap cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                // we get the image from the camera
            imgDumpCam .setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error:(24, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(24, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(24, 35) error: ')' expected
Error:(24, 37) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(24, 38) error: ';' expected
Error:(46, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Can you help me resolve the errors ?

Comment: Check out this code.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771172/fileuriexposedexception-when-create-separate-folder-for-captured-images/49771372#49771372

Comment: in above I can see some syntax error, is this code compile correctly

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `btnTake = h(View v);` this statement?  If you want to take the pic on the click of btnTake , do as follows

```
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

            public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10;
            private ImageView imgDumpCam;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
                imgDumpCam = findViewById(R.id.imgDumpCam);
                Button btnTake = findViewById(R.id.your_btn_take_id);
                btnTake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                //If user choose okay than following code will work
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                        //we are hearing back from camera
                        Bitmap cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        // we get the image from the camera
                        imgDumpCam.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: just import it. Add `import com.none.www.aarogya.R` in the imports

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code to get image from camera

first of all add  camera permission  in menifest.xml
and check runtimepermission

and then add this code

```
    login=findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickImageFromCamera();
        }
    });
}

public void clickImageFromCamera() {
       Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (camIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(camIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
}
/*on activity result */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {

        }
    }
}
```

i have this code is work for . if you have any problem in code comment me